Unity Steam Inventory Service
I would like some assistance in writing a system into my unity game, that drops an item from the common lootpool every 2 hours, and an item from the rare lootpool every 10 hours. My unity game is simple clicker game, that contains a clickable image, and when you click the image the text number goes up by 1. I already have steamworks.net implemented, I would like an assistance in the structure of the JSON file (ItemDefinitons.json) that you upload on the steamworks website, and a script that tells steam to drop an item from the common lootpool every 2 hours, and an item from the rare lootpool every 10 hours. Also, you have to click at least once in these timestamps, thank you a lot! If you want me to contact you, please write your contact in the comments! Thanks!
using UnityEngine;
using Steamworks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ItemDropManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int ThreeHourInterval = 7200;
    private const int EighteenHourInterval = 36000; // 18 hours in seconds
    private List<int> threeHourItems = new List<int> { ITEM_DEF_ID1, ITEM_DEF_ID2 }; // will replace with item def ids, just help me make the json file using steam inventory schema
    private List<int> eighteenHourItems = new List<int> { ITEM_DEF_ID3, ITEM_DEF_ID4 }; // will replace with item def ids, just help me make the json file using steam inventory schema
    private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(CheckForItemDrop), 0, 180); // 3 minute checks
    }

    private void CheckForItemDrop()
    {
        long lastThreeHourDropTime = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LastThreeHourDropTime", 0);
        long lastEighteenHourDropTime = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LastEighteenHourDropTime", 0);
        long currentTime = (long)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

        if (currentTime - lastThreeHourDropTime >= ThreeHourInterval)
        {
            RequestItemDrop(threeHourItems);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastThreeHourDropTime", (int)currentTime);
        }

        if (currentTime - lastEighteenHourDropTime >= EighteenHourInterval)
        {
            RequestItemDrop(eighteenHourItems);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastEighteenHourDropTime", (int)currentTime);
        }
    }

    private void RequestItemDrop(List<int> itemDefs)
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, itemDefs.Count);
        int itemDefId = itemDefs[randomIndex];

        SteamInventoryResult_t result;
        bool success = SteamInventory.AddPromoItem(out result, (SteamItemDef_t)itemDefId);

        if (success)
        {
            SteamInventoryResultReady_t callback = new SteamInventoryResultReady_t
            {
                m_handle = result
            };
            OnInventoryResultReady(callback);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to initiate item drop.");
        }
    }

    private void OnInventoryResultReady(SteamInventoryResultReady_t pCallback)
    {
        if (pCallback.m_result == EResult.k_EResultOK)
        {
            Debug.Log("Items granted successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to grant items: " + pCallback.m_result);
        }
    }
}



Steam handles most of this for you if you configure your items correctly, see https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/inventory/schema for more details, for timed drops, you need to setup use_drop_limit, drop_limit, drop_interval, for a few items I'd just write JSON manually, however I wont do this work for you.

You can use the example provided by steam:
{
    "appid": 480,
    "items": [
    {
        "itemdefid": 10,
        "type": "playtimegenerator",
        "bundle": "100x100;101x50;102x25;103x2;110x20;111x20;120x5;121x3",
        "name": "Drop Generator",
        "name_color":  "7D6D00",
        "background_color":  "3C352E",
        "item_slot": "generator",
        "icon_url": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "icon_url_large": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "tradable": false,
        "marketable": false
    },
    {
        "itemdefid": 100,
        "type":  "item",
        "name": "Hat decoration",
        "description": "Hat decoration description",
        "price": "1;USD99",
        "name_color":  "7D6D00",
        "background_color":  "3C352E",
        "item_slot": "decoration",
        "icon_url": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "icon_url_large": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "tradable": true,
        "marketable": true
    },
    {
        "itemdefid": 200,
        "type":  "item",
        "price": "1;VLV100",
        "name_english": "Red Hat",
        "name_german":  "Roter Hut",
        "description_english": "Red Hat",
        "description_german": "Roter Hut",
        "store_tags": "hat;featured",
        "icon_url": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "icon_url_large": "http://cdn.beta.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/c_fireaxe_pyro_xmas_large.fa878752e1aa09a721a03042a234063b6c929278.png",
        "tradable": true,
        "marketable": true
    }
    ]
}


Please see How can I handle off-site contact links in the question?
